# How to derive the solution in quadratic optimization

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm reading the book "Convex Analysis and Optimization" written by Prof. Bertsekas. In `Example 2.2.1`, there are the following description:

[image]

I don't know how to derive the equation `2.2`. Could anyone help give a hint, please? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

With the references kindly provided by KittyL, I have the following understanding:

The problem is to project the vector `-c` into the subspace $X=\{x|Ax=0\}$. Suppose the projection vector in the subspace is $x^*$, then because $x^*$ in the subspace, thus we have $Ax^*=0$. And the error vector is $-c-x^*$, which is perpendicular to the vectors in the subspace, thus we have $(-c-x^*)^Tx=0,\forall x\in X$.

The problem is also to project the vector `-c` into the null space of $A$. To this end, because the error vector $-c-x^*$ is in the column space of $A^T$ and $x^*$ is in the null space of $A$, and the projection matrix which projects the $-c$ into the the column space of $A^T$ is $A^T{(AA^T)}^{-1}A$ (from Reference 1). Thus, the projection matrix which projects the $-c$ into the null space of $A$ is $I-A^T{(AA^T)}^{-1}A$ (from Reference 2), and the projection vector that is in the null space of $A$ is $(I-A^T{(AA^T)}^{-1}A)(-c)$, which is also the vector $x^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/least-squares-determinants-and-eigenvalues/projections-onto-subspaces/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses2.2sum.pdf

It shows you how to project a vector onto the span of $A$.

Then here:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/least-squares-determinants-and-eigenvalues/projection-matrices-and-least-squares/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses2.3sum.pdf

This shows you how to project a vector onto the null space of $A$.

What you need is to project $-c$ onto the null space of $A$.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your kindly references! That's very helpful! I've updated the post with my new understanding of this problem, if I understood correctly. But I'm still not familiar with that. If you had time, please help check it. Thanks!

Comment: I think it is mostly correct. I just found the two paragraph a little redundant. I think you can omit the first paragraph, and just make a note at the beginning of the second paragraph that the space $X=\{x|Ax=0\}$ is the null space of $A$. And the "thus" in the second line should possibly be "since"?

Comment: Yes, I've corrected it. Thank you!